# Area bounded by circle $x^2+y^2=4$, $y=x^2+x+1$ and the curve $ \left\lfloor \sin^2\frac{x}{4}+\cos\frac{x}{4} \right\rfloor $ and the $x$ axis is

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Prove that the area bounded by circle $x^2+y^2=4$,the parabola $y=x^2+x+1$ and the curve $ \left\lfloor \sin^2\frac{x}{4}+\cos\frac{x}{4} \right\rfloor $ and the $x$ axis is $\sqrt3+\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{1}{6}.$

---

In this question,$x^2+y^2=4$ is a circle centered at $(0,0)$ and radius is $2$ and parabola $y=x^2+x+1$ faces upwards whose vertex is $(\frac{-1}{2},\frac{3}{4})$.
$I=2\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{4-y^2}dy-\int_{-1}^{0}1-(x^2+x+1)dx=\sqrt3+\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{1}{6}$
Thanks i now understood after help from RobertZ.

Comment: The best way to achieve this kind of problems is sketching a graph. Do you now how to plot a circle, a parabolla and the function $\left\lfloor \sin^2\frac{x}{4}+\cos\frac{x}{4} \right\rfloor$? I think the last function is a bit hard, so you probably will need a program that graphs. Then you proceed normally by integrating.

Comment: @user984325 Well done!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Inside the circle we have that $x\in [-2,2]$ which implies that $\cos(x/4)\in  [0,1]$. Therefore 
$$\sin^2\frac{x}{4}+\cos\frac{x}{4}=1+\cos\frac{x}{4}(1-\cos\frac{x}{4})\in [1,1+\frac{1}{4}]$$
Hence $\left\lfloor \sin^2\frac{x}{4}+\cos\frac{x}{4} \right\rfloor=1$ for $x\in [-2,2]$, which means that inside the circle, that curve is simply an horizontal segment.

Now make a drawing and try to find the area as an integral.

Comment: I understood,thanks.

Comment: @user984325 Did you find the integral to evaluate? Please edit your question and show us your progress.

Comment: ok i am showing

Comment: @user984325 Was my answer of any help?